# Swift - Reach another program for doing something

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

I wonder about some apps how they work. I researched something but I didn't find anything yet. You see some apps that lock a app ( whatsapp , instagram etc.) and unlock via these apps.

Ex: 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/1password-password-manager/id568903335?platform=iphone&preserveScrollPosition=true#platform/iphone

How do they control another apps?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that they 'control' other apps, maybe the app is just active in memory somewhere with your permission and when it receives a message that the system is attempting to open another app it comes on screen before the other app......Just like how you get notification on your phone when the app is closed.

This is just my guess as I don't know exactly how they work and since this question is for brainstorming more than a specific answer

Comment: maybe it will be the exit point of many applications if we find the real answer. thanks for reply